# EGOTableViewPullRefresh crash

Tags: iphone, sdk, pull-to-refresh

Xcode 4 tells me that it crashes on this line of code: `view.delegate = self;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.title = @"Blog";

    if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

        EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        view.delegate = self;
        [self.tableView addSubview:view];
        _refreshHeaderView = view;
        [view release]; 
    }
    [_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];
}
```

Do you have any idea why it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

You're over-releasing the view. You init `view`, you then assign it to `_refreshHeaderView`, and then you immediately release `view`.

When you do this:

`_refreshHeaderView = view;`

...you're telling _refreshHeaderView to point to the memory location that `view` corresponds to. `view` has a retain count of 1, because you've alloc/init'd it. And then in the next line you release `view`, which means its retain count is 0, so the object no longer exists (I am simplifying here: you also add it as a subview, which would increment the retain count. But the point is if you don't need to release it here).

That also means _refreshHeaderView no longer exists either, because **both view and _refreshHeadView are the same object**. So when you call `refreshLastUpdatedDate` you'll get a bad access, and a crash.

Getting rid of the `[view release]` should stop the crash, but you should be very careful to make sure you release that object later on when you're done with it (presumably in your dealloc method). It would be advisable to make `refreshHeaderView` a property to help with this.

Comment: no its still crash even when i remove the line [view release] :(